# JavaScript - Change dropdown Index and Text

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

On page load:

```
Select nazione_pr:  Text ITA Index 118

Select nazione_fatturazione: Text Afghanistan Index 1
```

After this function is excute

```
var x=document.getElementById("nazione_pr").selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementById("nazione_pr").options;
var w=document.getElementById("nazione_spedizione").selectedIndex;
var z=document.getElementById("nazione_spedizione").options;


alert (y[x].text);
alert (z[w].text);
w=x;
z[w].text=y[x].text;
alert (z[w].text);

document.getElementById("nazione_spedizione").disabled=true;
```

Then I get

```
Select nazione_pr:  Text ITA Index 118

Select nazione_fatturazione: Text Afghanistan **Index 118**
```

Why did the text not change?

Comment: You change only `selectedIndex`, why text should change?
Where `x` and `w` variables are initialized?

Comment: no, i use z[w].text=y[x].text; too...

Answer (score 1):

To change seleted index

```
var element = document.getElementById('yourcomboboxname');
element.selectedIndex = 0;
```

To change get value for selected index

```
var pName = document.getElementById('yourcomboboxname');
var value = pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].value;
```

To change text of selected index

```
pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].text = "your value of text";
```

Comment: dosent work... althought the text attribute change the seen text of dorpdown doesn't refresh and continue to stay afganistan...